# cfhttp not working on lucee

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, lucee

Rather confused here. From my local development machine (OSX), I can't get a dead simple cfhttp call to work (no ssl or anything). These work on my production machine. Both environments should be identical (docker).

On the dev machine, I have tried several different domains/urls:

Lucee version: 4.5.2.018, Apache Tomcat/8.0.28

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.learncfinaweek.com" method="get"></cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#cfhttp#"><cfabort>
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheesh, after struggling with this for an hour I eventually restarted the docker-machine with `docker-machine restart default`, restarted the containers, and cfhttp started working again.

As far as why it started happening in the first place, I'm not sure.